# assigning a variable to instance of a class and then keep updating it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create an instance of a class that holds an external variable. The class should keep updating the external variable that is being changed continuously.

Here is my code that will explain what I mean to say. However this code will not update the variable assigned to the class because my approach is not correct.

```
class Update_variable(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, VariablName):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.VariablName = VariablName

    def run(self):
        while True:
            variable = self.VariablName
            print("Value updated to: ", variable)           
            time.sleep(1.0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    var1 = 0.0
    var2 = 1.1
    update_var1 = Update_variable(var1)
    update_var2 = Update_variable(var2)
    update_var1.start()
    update_var2.start()
    while True:
        var1 = random()
        var2 = random()
        print("New value for var1: ",var1)
        print("New value for var2: ",var2)
        time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: It is something we call pointer based access in C and C++. I dont know how to accomplish in python where I assign an external variable name and NOT its value.

Comment: Why is it necessary to use threads? What is your main objective? I suspect you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)

Comment: The code above is for concept. My actual code is for a GUI interface using PyQt

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with PyQt since they are general python concepts. On the other hand the answer depends on the context, it is not the same to execute everything synchronously, to use multithreading or multiprocesing, etc.

Comment: @Iftikhar note, the linked docs are telling you that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this way, because variables are passed by assignment.

But the Python documentation itself gives us some options: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference